# Internet Explorer: whitelines around pictures, missing pictures

Tags: asp.net, html, css, image, internet-explorer

I am making a website http://projects.knord.dk/grjenie31/home.aspx
And in IE 9 I see white lines around the logo and top picture... and furthermore in the area below the logo of the bird there should be some photos of sponsors... which are not there.

Does anybody know how to solve it? It works in Chrome and FireFox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your CSS:

```
img {
border:0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the missing images is because of your javascript. You have double scripts that hide images, try removing one.